# How to allow cards to wrap in list-groups?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Currently, I am trying to see if there is a way to allow cards within a list-group to wrap if there is not enough space. For example, I have 4 cards in a list group - all set to have a width of 25%. How would I make sure that the fifth card is in the row below.

I have already tried looking up this issue online, however, some of the solutions I have found seem sloppy, for example, having a second group list.

```
<div class="list-group-item active text-light w-25">
    <h5 class="mb-1">text</h5>
    <p class="mb-1">text</p>
</div>
```

I expect the cards to wrap once more than 4 are shown, however, there could be 8 in a singular row.

Comment: Still don't have a solution to this problem

Comment: Have you tried experimenting with Bootstrap grid and flex with cards? I think you may be able to achieve what you are looking for by applying grid on cards.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible in bootstrap 4, correct me if I'm mistaken but this seems to be a limitation, perhaps try javascript?

Answer (score -1):

Further to my comment above, see below code snippet that aligns 4 cards in a row and applies responsiveness if screen size reduces. For each card, I have set it up to use 3 grid spaces on large screens, 6 on medium and 12 on small screens so that you can achieve responsiveness.You can adjust the grid spacing as per your requirement.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid py-2">
  <div class="row"> 
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3 col-xl-3 mb-1"><div class="card p-5">Card 1</div></div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3 col-xl-3 mb-1"><div class="card p-5">Card 2</div></div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3 col-xl-3 mb-1"><div class="card p-5">Card 3</div></div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3 col-xl-3 mb-1"><div class="card p-5">Card 4</div></div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3 col-xl-3 mb-1"><div class="card p-5">Card 5</div></div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3 col-xl-3 mb-1"><div class="card p-5">Card 6</div></div>
  </div>
 </div>
```